# Iterate over columns using conditional in python?

Tags: python

When working with a DataFrame, is there a way to change the value of a cell based on a value in a column?

For example, I have a DataFrame of exam results that looks like this:

```
  answer_is_a answer_is_c
0           a           a
1           b           b
2           c           c
```

I want to code them as correct (`1`) and incorrect(`0`). So it would look like this:

```
  answer_is_a answer_is_c
0           1           0
1           0           0
2           0           1
```

So I need to iterate over the entire DataFrame, compare what is already in the cell with the last character of the column header, and then change the cell value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `DataFrame.apply` iterates through the columns, passing each as a series to the function you feed it. Series have a `name` attribute that is a string we'll use to extract the answer.

So you could do this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas
data = StringIO("""\
answer_is_a answer_is_c
          a           a
          b           b
          c           c
""")
x = (
    pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+')
        .apply(lambda col: col == col.name.split('_')[-1])
        .astype(int)
)
```

And `x` prints out as:

```
   answer_is_a  answer_is_c
0            1            0
1            0            0
2            0            1
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul H! What if I had a situation where there were two possible answers?

For example, in the first column, what if the fact that `col.name.split('_')[-1]` returns `a` means that both `a` and `c` are correct answers?

Comment: @NCG same basic principle applies. write a function that returns a list of the valid answers from the column name  (call it `valid_answers`) then do `lambda c: c.isin(valid_answers(c.name))`

Comment: Got it. Magic. Thank you!